# Tracking down Source of interrupts

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos7, interrupt-handling, irq

I've got Xeon-D based platform running CentOS 7.3 ( Linux kernel 3.10.0-862) and I've noticed a lot of unhandled interrupts coming to a particular IRQ (IRQ#18). The IRQ line seems to be shared by USB host controller and an SMBus driver, however the interrupts keep on coming even after disabling all USB ports in BIOS and unloading the i2c-i801 module (one at a time, to keep the kernel listening to IRQ line). Therefore, I'm at a loss to track down where these interrupts are coming from, if not from USB or I2C.

Eventually, things get so bad that the kernel simply disables the IRQ (*irq 18: nobody cared ...*), causing things to stop working on the smbus.
The only way to keep it going is to use *noirqdebug* parameter in my kernel boot cmdline.

I've observed the same issue when running Ubuntu 18.04, with a newer kernel.

I've got following questions:

- How do IRQ numbers get assigned at kernel and  device levels?
- Is it possible that something not on the USB or SMBus could be sending interrupts to IRQ#18?
- How does one go about tracking down the source of these interrupts?

and finally,

- How to fix this? :-)

I'd appreciate any suggestions or pointers and I'll be happy to provide any information I might've missed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do `lspci -v | less` and search for IRQ 18, are there any PCI devices using it?

Comment: Just the two - the USB controller (EHCI) and the SMBUS controller

Comment: If the interrupts came from the USB or SMBus controllers, their drivers would have handled them. So it must be some other hardware. Mainboard model?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried the "irqpoll" option to see if the kernel is able to find any interrupt handler for them at all, but to no avail. The Mainboard is a custom carrier that I'm trying to verify for functionality